# I want to call javascript class from html button on Click event how to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, class

**HTML code**

**As you can this how to call the class method from HTML**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <button onclick="st.show()">Click</button>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**I want to display the username in console**

**Javascript code**

```
class Student{
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    show(){
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
let name=document.getElementById('userName').value;
var st=new Student(name);
```

Comment: Where is `emp` defined?

Comment: Change `emp.show()` to `st.show()` since `st` is what you declared.

Comment: I still got the same error.

Comment: Problem with that: let name=document.getElementById('userName').value;

Comment: you can write another function and call show function. Then call the newly added function onclick. There is another issue with the class class constructor. set the name as 'this.name = name'

Comment: Problem you have is the name is being to be set when the page loads, not when the user updates the textbox.

Comment: I think you are be looking for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318501/call-class-instance-method-onclick-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. name should be set as "`this.name = name`". and show function should log `this.name` instead of `this.username`.

```
class Student {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  show() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

Add the below function.

```
function show() {
  let name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var st = new Student(name);
  st.show();
}
```

Call `show()` function on button click instead of `emp.show()`

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <button onclick="show()">Click</button>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: did u change this.name = name; in constructor? and console.log(this.name); in show() function. please compare the code in class.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the variable name with a property?

```
constructor(name){
    name=this.name;  <-- you have this reversed
}
```

You are referencing a property you never set

```
show(){
    console.log(this.username) <-- what is username?
}
```

}

You are reading the value when the page loads

```
let name=document.getElementById('userName').value;
```

Basic idea using getter and setter

```js
class Student {
  _name = "unknown"
  constructor() {
  }
  set name(name) {
    this._name = name
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
  reverseName() {
    return [...this._name].reverse().join("");
  }
}

const st = new Student();
document.getElementById("userName").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  st.name = e.target.value;
});

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  console.log(st.name);
});

document.getElementById("rev").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  console.log(st.reverseName());
});
```

```html
<label for="username">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="userName">
<button type="button" id="show">Click</button>
<button type="button" id="rev">Reverse</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if this helps:

```js
class Student{
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    show(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

function empShow(){
    let name = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    var st = new Student(name);
    return st.show();
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="userName">
        <button onclick="empShow()">Click</button>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry @epascarello for sharing this wrong code please check once again I am updating ...